# Client side connection issues need help

Tags: login

I'm having issues connecting to a Web based Sharepoint share. When I attempt to connect to the server it appears to reject my username and password. It appears to be an issue with the image on our Desktops, as other systems that are not using this image can connect(from our network). The login box pops up, I enter in the username/password and then it immediatley pops back up again almost as if the user name/PW has been rejected.

The sharepoint that I am trying to connect to is on a seperate Domain that has nothing to do with us.

I'm not really sure what I am missing. Our client side machines are Windows XP SP3. Any ideas or tips would be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it's on a separate domain, then you'll probably need to login with the appropraite domain\username and password in your authentication prompt that the SharePoint site is expecting.

You can also login with your full email address and password.